# Action Script 3.0

Tags: flash, actionscript

I'm new to AS 3.0 - I have a class file with public static variables with ​​declared values . I need to know **when I change any value of the variables in the main class file** (.as), there is some routine (event) to do the **SWF update these values in dynamic textField (on stage) without re-export the SWF.**?

Thanks for any answer!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of static variables use static getters and setters. For example:

```
package  {

    public class MyClass {

        private static var _property:Number;

        public static function set property(value:Number):void {
            _property = value;
            // update your text field's value here
        }
        public static function get property():Number {
            return _property;
        }

    }

}
```

The code could be used like that:

```
MyClass.property = 10;
trace(MyClass.property);
```

it will print *10*.

Comment: Dear Krasimir, I'm really grateful for your guidance, but I tried to use the textField but still did not work. Maybe I'm doing something wrong, but I'm sending this link: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/70043653/Getters_Setters.rar  the test file where I used his example. If in case you want to see, I'm grateful. thank you – Fran Ildefonso 45 mins ago

Comment: I compiled your fla and saw 30 in the text field. Isn't it that what you want?

Comment: I need the following: The variables of the class file will be changed from time to time, so I'm looking for a solution (an event) that can update the swf (swf directly on) without having to recompile the fla.
The original file (my work) is here if you want to see:https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/70043653/RMS.rar

Comment: You may put whatever you want on the place of *// update your text field's value here*. The idea is that you have to inject some logic there. And once the property is changed just do something. This could be (as you want) an event dispatching or text field value changing.

Comment: Got! I will follow your instructions. Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Your web site is very nice! If you'll need any image from Brazil I'll can send to you.